# What is the batch script to open another cmd window to run another line of script

Tags: batch-file, scripting, cmd

I know that the question was not very clear, so I will try to make it clearer.
I am looking for the batch script command to open a cmd window that runs like a batch program.
I know the command exists as I have seen it used before and have used it before, however, as of late I have not been
able to find it or remember it. The command looks something like this

```
@echo off
start cmd.exe ("@echo off && echo second window opened && pause")
pause
```

It would open a second cmd window that read.

```
second window opened
press any key to continue...
```

And when you pressed a key the second window would close, just like a batch file cmd window would. As you probably can tell I am relatively new to batch scripts and am still a little iffy on how it works.

Comment: Have you looked at `cmd.exe`'s options?

Comment: yes, but is there something you saw in there that I missed?

Comment: Did you try it? You cannot expect us to do your own work. I strongly suggest you try this out, see if you get the expected result. If you don't, then try debugging your script. Then, if you run into a situation you cannot solve by googleing, post your questions here.

Comment: To answer Laf. No I am not expecting you to do my work, I do not have a batch debugging program, I did google it and look it up on this website, and I did not know cmd.exe could be /?ed. As I said in the question I am new to both batch programming and this website, in fact this is my first question. So please take it easy on me as I am still learning the ropes.

Comment: My comment wasn't meant as an insult. As per SO's policies, we expect people to try by themselves, and do some research, before posting questions here. On a technical note, always keep in mind that `.exe` files can _almost_ always be called with a `/?` argument (or `-h`) to get some help on the executable. These will answer most of your questions.

Comment: (yeah...I am used to being able to press enter in a comment section and not have it post it...yeah I'm new) I'm sorry I did not mean to imply that you were insulting me. I am just new to using the language and finding answers to questions that I would like answered about it. So...yeah some of my questions might sound a little stupid to someone who has used the language for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Not bad memory. Almost done

```
start "title" cmd /c "echo in other window & echo. & pause"
```

Type `cmd /?` and `start /?` to get all the needed information for this commands usage